# Three.js and web workers weird behavior

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl, web-worker

I have some strange things going on using web workers in a three.js application. On first load of a new page it looks fine.

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/42766757/beforezoom.png

But then after a few page reloads (like 20), and ONLY when web workers are executing, this happens:

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/42766757/afterzoom.png

Thats my cube up in the top right corner! For some reason it seems to zoom in after 20 or so reloads.

But then if I resize my screen to be smaller, the cube pops back into the middle. I checked to see if the ratio of screen height/width was always the same at the point where the cube would snap back and it isn't.

Also, if I continue reloading the page it gets to the point where the cube disappears, and eventually the screen goes blank. But then I reload the page again **in a new window** and everything is back in place.

At first I thought it might have something to do with the web workers not terminating properly, so I set up a `beforeunload` event handler that kills all of my workers, which didn't work. So I'm not sure what's going on here. Help!

I'm using chrome 24 and it doesn't seem to be an issue in firefox 18.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've also bumped into this earlier - it is a bug in Chrome / Webkit. However, with Chrome 25 beta I haven't seen it anymore.

Here's some references:

- https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=105367
- https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=133751